# Creating a storage class, sorted and limited by weight

Tags: java, arraylist, storage

Sorry for asking this, but i could really use a new PoV. Been sitting on it for days and can't wrap my head around it.

Basically, i have a `Class Screw`, whose object has attributes like length, material etc. It also saves the amount of screws and the weight this amount has.

So basically it sets `Screw1 = 1cm, Steel, 200 Screws, 10kg` (not like that of course, but for simplicities sake)

Those Screw objects are to be saved in a storage unit, sorted. So every combination of attributes gets it's own space to be saved in. It is limited by weight, so if you add 25kg of screws, you'd need two storage spaces, creating a new `box` to store them in.

It shall also be possible to take out screws, removing a storage space, if the weight of a box would drop below 0 and removing the remaining amount of screws from the new box.

```
public class Schraube {
private int schraubenArt,Material,SchraubenAnzahl, Entnahmeprotokoll;
private double durchmesser,laenge, gangHoehe,gaengigkeit,gewicht;

// lots of constructors and methods for calculations
}
```

I also had a storage class that would loop through all the possible combinations of `Schraube` and would then `.add()` them to an ArrayList, giving it maximum weight.

Now, how would you go about doing this? How do you add `Stoagespaces` if you go over weight 20kg? How would one do this efficiently without creating huge arrays of 561 spaces times 7?

I hope it's kinda clear what i am trying to do. Head hurts and i can't figure it out anymore.

Comment: What have you tried so far with the storage class? What methods do you have so far?

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Maybe you could add an example.

Comment: @Barret ArrayLists are a very new concept to me, so i had one method to fill them, using nested for loops, those adding the then created object to said list. Other than that i could get size, attributes of specific elements of the ArrayList, get the index of an object.

Comment: @SpiderPig What i want to do is this: Create a Screw. This Screw has certain attributes that make it unique. It is limited, otherwise there would be infinite possibilities. (so 3 lengths, 3 widths etc). The Object has a weight and a number of screws that are related. So 100 screws weigh 5kg for example. Now i want to put them in Storage. The storage contains boxes that each hold one SPECIFIC type of Screw and can take 20kg or 50kg or 100kg. If someone orders more, it needs to be put into new boxes or moved up the weightchain. Hope that helps :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advise would be not to create a storage class since the Schraube class does not represent a singular entity but the properties of multiple entities. In this case you are setting the number of screws in a class that represents a screw. There are two solutions to this problem.

1. Create a getter method that calculates the number of storage spaces.

   public int getNumberOfStorageSpaces(){
       .... // Calculation logic
       return numberOfStorageSpaces;
   }
2. Or you can separate the type entity from quantity. In this case you would remove the SchraubenAnzahl property from the Schraube class, create another entity that encapsulates the type and quantity of screws called Schrauben. Then you would need a StorageSpace entity that represents a space and the quantity it can hold. Finally you would need an entity that represents the relationship between screws and storage spaces. This would be a more complex solution. To better understand the issue I recommend using an Entity Relationship Diagram to better illustrate the relationship between your entities.